# Integration of $(u-\frac{1}{2})^ru^{\frac{n}{2}-1}(1-u)^{\frac{n}{2}-1}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to calculate the following integration?

$\int_0^1(u-\frac{1}{2})^ru^{\frac{n}{2}-1}(1-u)^{\frac{n}{2}-1}du$ where $n>0$

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: How are $n,\,r$ constrained, e.g. as integers? If $r$ can be any real, we'll have trouble when $u<\frac12$.

Comment: @J.G. n and r are integers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute $t=2u-1$ so the integral is $\frac{1}{2^{n+r-1}}\int_{-1}^1t^r(1-t^2)^{n/2-1}dt$, which vanishes for odd $r$. If $r$ is even, the integral is$$\frac{1}{2^{n+r-2}}\int_0^1t^r(1-t^2)^{n/2-1}dt=\frac{\operatorname{B}((r+1)/2,\,n/2)}{2^{n+r-1}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that:
$$\left(u-\frac 12\right)^r=\left[\frac 12(2u-1)\right]^r$$
and so we can write:
$$I=\frac 1{2^r}\int_0^1(2u-1)^ru^{n/2-1}(1-u)^{n/2-1}du$$
now if $x=2u-1$ then $u=(x+1)/2$ and $(1-u)=(1-x)/2$
and so we get:
$$I=\frac 1{2^r}\int_{-1}^1x^r\left(\frac{x+1}2\right)^{n/2-1}\left(\frac{1-x}2\right)^{n/2-1}\frac{dx}2=\frac{1}{2^{r+n-1}}\int_{-1}^1x^r(x+1)^{n/2-1}(1-x)^{n/2-1}dx$$
which can be represented in terms of the beta function for even $r$ and the integral is $0$ for odd $r$.